# Set URI Redirect with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

First of all, I am developing an AppEngine application. As framework, I am using jQuery Mobile. I use GMail API too.

To connect with GMail, I need to work with OAuth 2.0. I have set the credentials into my application (I already have client_secret.json into my project).

My situation is: I am in a JSP page when I call to my Java code (server side) to get my Gmail Service. For this task, I need to get the permissions (Oauth 2.0) from my user. Later, we need to redirect to my application.

My problem is what I do not know what I have to write exactly in "AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPTS ORIGINS" and "AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI".

I am testing my application in local mode and the normal URL is: localhost:8888/mobile/index.jsp

Can you help me?

Best regards,
Diego.

Comment: You can pass redirect URI into "state" parameter and redirect user on desired URL *after* he was redirected on redirect_uri and authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Details here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#Getkeysforyourapplication)

AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPTS ORIGINS  -> Protocols (ie HTTP and HTTPS) and domains (my-app-id.appspot.com) that can use JS and OAuth calls. For local add

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

. You will need to add one for the production URL as well.

AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI -> When doing OAtuh calls from the app it needs a handler setup to get responses from the OAuth server. Personally I use [decorators](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#Decorators), so my redirect URI is

```
http://localhost:8888/oauth2callback
```

. Yours will vary depending on how you handle the OAuth flow.

Comment: Hello Ryan, I am going to comment you as I have everything. My jsp file who is doing the OAuth calls is http://localhost:8888/mobile/inbox.jsp. When the calls are finished, I want to return to http://localhost:8888/mobile/index.jsp. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: I've done what you wrote above and I get: The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob did not match a registered redirect URI.